# How to make Parent and children share same open file limit

Tags: linux, bash, kernel

When I have a parent process have a limit of 128 files i.e and I fork, the children will also have 128 files, and if that child forks we'd have another 128 totaling 384. My question is, is it possible to limit this "tree" to share the limit of 128?

Sincerely

Answer (score 0):

you should find a possible solution by configuring `nofile` parameter in `/etc/security/limits.conf`, associated to an application dedicated user.

More informations with `man limits.conf`.